# Guano mines versus early artificial fertilizers?

Tags: science-based, technology, agriculture

Ok, so this is an very odd little question.

I've been working out the economy of an industrial age world; figuring the major industries, trade routes, etc. I have a tropical region I was considering putting a lot of guano mines in. In the real world, South American guano was prized as a valuable fertilizer. As supplies ran short, we turned to artificially synthesized ammonia instead.

It's not totally clear to me whether this was to satisfy demand, or because ammonia synthesis is in some way just that much more competitive; whether it results in a superior product, can be made faster and in larger bulk, costs much less to produce, etc. etc.

So, in a world where ammonia synthesis has recently become possible (in the last couple of decades), how likely would it be to seriously cut into an otherwise thriving guano mining industry?

Comment: The [Haber process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process) was discovered in 1910; the first industrial plant was built in Germany in 1913. It is very energy-intensive. From the very beginning it was used by those countries which _did not_ have access to natural reserves of nitrates, for example, Germany; those countries which did have access to natural reseves of nitrates did not use the artificial process until much later (during WW2, when shipping cheap nitrates from around the world while being hunted by submarines was not an attractive option). Today, there is no more cheap guano.

Comment: The *real* reason the Haber process was adopted by Germany was the British blockade during the Great War (1914-1918) prevented natural nitrates from being imported for fertilizer or explosive manufacturing. A similar reasoning drove Germany to adopt the F-T process to convert coal to oil in WWII.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ammonia can be synthesized from atmospheric nitrogen by the [Haber process](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/equilibria/haber.html).  But nearly as important as nitrogen is phosphorus (as phosphate) and you cannot make that out of air.  You need a mineral source or guano, which contains nitrogen and phosphorus.

The phosphorus content is what kept guano competitive with synthetic fertilizers into the mid 1900s.

Other reasons guano might stay competitive

1. Nationalist protectionism.  If a competitor state houses the industry with a secret method for NH3 production, I might tax imported NH3 to reduce profits for that industry and its parent state.  This will make my domestic guano industry more competitive.
2. Abundant local supply of guano and well established supply routes.  People like to do things the way they are used to doing them.
3. Synthetic ammonium nitrate fertilizer can be dangerous to transport.
   from http://highschoolenergy.acs.org/content/hsef/en/how-do-we-use-energy/history-of-nitrogen.html
   [image]

Comment: That's quite a disaster. The explosion *blew a **7200 ton ship** twenty feet in the air.* Damn!